# Efficient method to use excel checksheet data to create and populate a list in a new sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am working on a project, which takes a checksheet that the user creates and fills out 
[image]

and, when the user runs a macro, creates a new workbook that extrapolates and expands the checksheet data, as shown here

[image]

What it does is it goes through each of those number labor codes, and runs down the checksheet for all the applicable items, addending them to the list.

Now...I have this working fine, and run through the basic testing. I save the checksheet as an array and pass it through to the new workbook, filtering and creating the new workbook line-by-line.

I just can't help but think that there's a much easier way to do this, as the way I'm doing it now just doesn't seem to be the simplest and most stable way.

I'm open to sharing my code I have so far, but was wondering if you were given this senario, how you would approach it.

Here is the link to my file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gobdx1rcabquew/Checksheet_Template_R3.0%20-%20StkOvrflw.xls

Main module, which checks for errors and corrects formatting:

```
Option Explicit
    Public FamilyName As String
    Public ModelName As String
    Public TaskArray() As Variant
    Public TaskArrayRowCount As Integer
    Public TaskArrayColCount As Integer

Sub CreateTemplate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Main SubModule. Runs Formatting and Template Generation
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Dim TaskArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Range
    Dim MajMinYesNo As Boolean
    Dim OPOYesNo As Boolean

    If MsgBox("Are you ready to generate the Template?", vbYesNo, "Ready?") = vbNo Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End
    End If

    MajMinYesNo = False
    OPOYesNo = False
    Set thisWB = ActiveWorkbook
    FamilyName = thisWB.Names("Family_Name").RefersToRange
    ModelName = thisWB.Names("Model_No").RefersToRange

    Call CreateArray(thisWB)
    'Scans Form_Type Column for "R", "S", or "A-E"
    For Each i In Range("CS_FormType")
        If i Like "[RS]" Then
            MajMinYesNo = True
        ElseIf i Like "[A-E]" Then
            OPOYesNo = True
        End If
    Next

    'Generates Templates As Needed
    If MajMinYesNo Then
        If MsgBox("Generate Major/Minor Template?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            Call MajorMinor_Generate.GenerateMajorMinor(thisWB)
        End If
    End If
    If OPOYesNo Then
        If MsgBox("Generate OPO Template?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Call OPO_Generate.GenerateOPO(thisWB)
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("DONE!")
End Sub
Sub CreateArray(thisWB As Workbook)
'Checks formatting and creates array TaskArray() with all the checksheet data

    With thisWB.Sheets(1)
    'Confirms equal number of rows in columns "CS_TaskNo", "CS_FormType", and "CS_Task"
        If (Not Range("CS_TaskNo").Rows.count = Range("CS_FormType").Rows.count) _
            Or (Not Range("CS_TaskNo").Rows.count = Range("CS_Task").Rows.count) Then
            MsgBox ("Task_No, Form_Type, and Task_Desc row count does not match. Please fix and try again")
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End
        End If
        Call FormatCheck

        Application.Union(Range("CS_Heading"), Range("CS_TaskNo"), Range("CS_FormType"), Range("CS_Task"), Range("CS_LaborCodes"), Range("CS_Checks")).Name = "TaskArray"
        TaskArrayRowCount = Range("TaskArray").Rows.count
        TaskArrayColCount = Range("TaskArray").Columns.count
        ReDim TaskArray(TaskArrayRowCount, TaskArrayColCount)
        TaskArray = Range("TaskArray").Value
    End With
End Sub
Sub FormatCheck()
'Checks for valid labor codes and Form Types
    If (Not CheckFormType()) Or (Not CheckLC()) Then
        MsgBox ("Errors found, please check red-highlighted cells")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End
    End If
End Sub
Function CheckFormType()
'Returns False if there's a bad Form_Type entry in range "CS_FormType", True if all OK
    Dim i As Range
    Dim ReturnVal As Boolean

    ReturnVal = True
    For Each i In Range("CS_FormType")
        Trim (UCase(i.Value))
        If Not (i Like "[ABCDEFRS]") Then
            Highlight (Cells(i.Row, i.Column))
            ReturnVal = False
        End If
    Next
    CheckFormType = ReturnVal
End Function
Function CheckLC()
'Returns False if there's a bad error code, True if all OK _
Formats labor code ranges to add spaces as needed and checks _
labor codes for proper format (###X or ##X). Skips any labor _
codes starting with "28X"

    Dim LaborCode As String
    Dim LaborCodeLength As Integer
    Dim i As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim LCCell As Range
    Dim LCArray() As String
    Dim ReturnVal As Boolean

    ReturnVal = True

    For Each i In Range("CS_LaborCodes")
        Trim (UCase(i.Value))
        LaborCode = i.Value
        If Not Left(LaborCode, 3) Like "28?" Then
            LaborCodeLength = Len(LaborCode)
            'If string LaborCode is > 4, safe to assume it is a range of labor codes 123A-123F
            Select Case LaborCodeLength
            Case Is > 4
                'Formats Labor Code Range String by adding spaces if necessary (i.e. 123A-123F to 123A - 123F)
                For j = 2 To LaborCodeLength Step 1
                    If (IsNumeric(Mid(LaborCode, j, 1))) And Not IsNumeric(Mid(LaborCode, j + 1, 1)) And Not (Mid(LaborCode, j + 2, 1) = " ") Then
                        LaborCode = Left(LaborCode, j + 1) & " " & Mid(LaborCode, j + 2)
                    ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(LaborCode, j, 1)) And Not (Mid(LaborCode, j - 1, 1) = " ") And Not IsNumeric(Mid(LaborCode, j - 1, 1)) Then
                        LaborCode = Left(LaborCode, j - 1) & " " & Mid(LaborCode, j)
                    End If
                Next
                i = LaborCode
                LCArray = Split(LaborCode, " ")
                'confirms the labor codes are valid
                If (Not IsLaborCode(LCArray(0))) Or (Not IsLaborCode(LCArray(2))) Or (Not IsLaborCodeRange(LCArray(0), LCArray(2))) Then
                    Highlight (Cells(i.Row, i.Column))
                    ReturnVal = False
                End If
            Case 0 To 4
                If Not (IsLaborCode(LaborCode)) Then
                    Highlight (Cells(i.Row, i.Column))
                    ReturnVal = False
                End If
            Case Else
                Highlight (Cells(i.Row, i.Column))
                ReturnVal = False
            End Select
        End If
    Next
    CheckLC = ReturnVal
End Function
Function IsLaborCode(LC As String) As Boolean
'returns True if Labor Code is valid, False if invalid _
Labor Code is valid if it is 2 or 3 numbers followed by a letter _
labor code format : ###X or ##X
    If LC Like "###[A-Z]" Or LC Like "##[A-Z]" Then
        IsLaborCode = True
    Else
        IsLaborCode = False
    End If
End Function
Function IsLaborCodeRange(LCOne As String, LCTwo As String) As Boolean
'returns True if the LC range is valid, False if invalid. _
checks the numerical values to make sure they match and _
makes sure the letters are ascending
    If (StrComp(Left(LCOne, Len(LCOne) - 1), Left(LCTwo, Len(LCTwo) - 1)) = 0) And LCOne < LCTwo Then
        IsLaborCodeRange = True
    Else
        IsLaborCodeRange = False
    End If
End Function
```

And here is the other module which actually takes the array and creates the new workbook:

```
Sub GenerateMajorMinor(thisWB As Workbook)
    Dim newWB As Workbook
    Dim MajMinArray() As Variant

    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    With newWB
        Call FormatWorkbook
        Call CreateMajMinArray(newWB, MajMinArray)
        Call PopulateItemMaster(MajMinArray)
        Call PopulateLaborLink(MajMinArray)
        Call SaveFile(newWB, thisWB)
    End With
End Sub
Sub SaveFile(newWB As Workbook, thisWB As Workbook)
    'saves new workbook into the same file path as the checksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FileSavePath As String
    Dim FamNameSave As String

    FamNameSave = Replace(FamilyName, "/", "_")

    i = 1
    FileSavePath = thisWB.Path + "/Template (Minor and Major)_" + FamNameSave + ".xls"

a:    If Dir(FileSavePath) <> "" Then
        FileSavePath = thisWB.Path + "/Template (Minor and Major)_" + FamNameSave + "(" + CStr(i) + ").xls"
        i = i + 1
        GoTo a:
    End If
    newWB.SaveAs FileSavePath, FileFormat:=56
End Sub
Sub FormatWorkbook()
    'Names and formats sheets
    Sheets(1).Name = "Item_Master"
    Sheets(2).Name = "Labor_Link"

    With Sheets(1)
        .Range("A1") = "Company_No"
        .Range("B1") = "Family_Name"
        .Range("C1") = "Form_Type"
        .Range("D1") = "Record_Status"
        .Range("E1") = "Task_Desc"
        .Range("F1") = "Task_No"
        .Range("G1") = "Task_Seq"
        .Range("H1") = "Is_Parametric"
    End With
    With Sheets(2)
        .Range("A1") = "Company_Name"
        .Range("B1") = "Family_Name"
        .Range("C1") = "Form_Type"
        .Range("D1") = "Labor_Code"
        .Range("E1") = "Print_Control"
        .Range("F1") = "Record_Status"
        .Range("G1") = "Task_No"
    End With
End Sub
Sub CreateMajMinArray(newWB As Workbook, MajMinArray As Variant)
    'creates array, removing any OPO/BTS labor codes
    With Sheets(3)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(TaskArrayRowCount, TaskArrayColCount))
    rng = TaskArray
    For i = 1 To .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row Step 1
            If .Cells(i, 2) Like "[A-E]" Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
                i = i - 1
            End If
        Next
        For i = 1 To .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column Step 1
            If Left(.Cells(1, i), 3) Like "28E" Then
                .Columns(i).Delete
                i = i - 1
            End If
        Next
        ReDim MajMinArray(.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column)
        MajMinArray = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column)).Value
        .Cells.Clear
    End With
End Sub
Sub PopulateItemMaster(MajMinArray As Variant)
    With Sheets(1)
        'Populates "Item_Master" Sheet
        For i = 2 To UBound(MajMinArray) Step 1
            .Cells(i, 2) = FamilyName
            .Cells(i, 3) = MajMinArray(i, 2)
            .Cells(i, 4) = "1"
            .Cells(i, 5) = MajMinArray(i, 3)
            .Cells(i, 6) = MajMinArray(i, 1)
            .Cells(i, 7) = MajMinArray(i, 1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
Sub PopulateLaborLink(MajMinArray As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LaborCode As String
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim LCArray() As String
    Dim LastLetter As String
    Dim LastFormType As String

    'Initializes RowCount and PrintControl
    RowCount = 2
    PrintControl = 10

    With Sheets(2)
        For i = 4 To UBound(MajMinArray, 2) Step 1
            LaborCode = Trim(MajMinArray(1, i))
    'If Labor Code String length is > 4, safe to assume that it is a range of labor codes
            Select Case Len(LaborCode)
            Case Is > 4
                LCArray = Split(LaborCode, " ")
        'checks to see if LCArray(0) and LCArray(2) has values
        If LCArray(0) = "" Or LCArray(2) = "" Then
                    MsgBox ("Error with Labor Code range. Please check and re-run")
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    End
                End If

                LastLetter = Chr(Asc(Right$(LCArray(2), 1)) + 1)
                LCArray(2) = Replace(LCArray(2), Right$(LCArray(2), 1), LastLetter)
                Do
                    Call PrintLaborLinkLines(MajMinArray, LCArray(0), RowCount, i)
                    LastLetter = Chr(Asc(Right$(LCArray(0), 1)) + 1)
                    LCArray(0) = Replace(LCArray(0), Right$(LCArray(0), 1), LastLetter)
                Loop Until LCArray(0) = LCArray(2)
                Erase LCArray()
            Case Is <= 4
                Call PrintLaborLinkLines(MajMinArray, LaborCode, RowCount, i)
            End Select
        Next
    End With
End Sub
Sub PrintLaborLinkLines(MajMinArray As Variant, LaborCode As String, RowCount As Long, i As Integer)
    Dim PrintControl As Long

    PrintControl = 10
    With Sheets(2)
        For x = 2 To UBound(MajMinArray) Step 1
            If UCase(MajMinArray(x, i)) = "Y" Then
                If LastFormType <> MajMinArray(x, 2) Then
                    PrintControl = 10
                End If
                .Cells(RowCount, 2) = FamilyName
                .Cells(RowCount, 3) = MajMinArray(x, 2)
                .Cells(RowCount, 4) = LaborCode
                .Cells(RowCount, 5) = PrintControl
                .Cells(RowCount, 6) = "1"
                .Cells(RowCount, 7) = MajMinArray(x, 1)
                RowCount = RowCount + 1
                PrintControl = PrintControl + 10
                LastFormType = MajMinArray(x, 2)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Improve your question and share your code. We can't show you 'simpler way' if we don't know the current one ;(

Comment: @MaciejLos Sorry, just added a link to the file!

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not interested of file and i don't want to download it. Please, copy and paste your code.

Comment: Apologies. Uploaded the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If restructuring the order of the data on the new sheet is possible it seems as though you could copy only visible cells and then write a simple loop to bring in any data that is not explicit (ie Labor Code).